# Ruby date skips a date on local console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I see this in my Rails console

```
[7] pry(main)> Date.today
=> Sat, 16 Sep 2017
[8] pry(main)> Date.tomorrow
=> Mon, 18 Sep 2017
```

What could be the reason for missing a date (17 Sep)?

Comment: It's obvious: you executed `Date.today`  a moment before midnight.

Comment: Yes I agree what @CarySwoveland said.